# How to avoid git of downloading specified some files from main repository

Tags: git

How could I avoid git of downloading specified some files from main repository? I would like to exclude some javascript files that I don't want to be on the webserver.

Is there any "gitignore" that prevents download of specific files?

Comment: Give some details on what you are doing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with the "sparse checkout" feature.

```
git config core.sparsecheckout true
```

Edit the `.git/info/sparse-checkout` file and add:

```
*
!invisible.js
```

Then:

```
git read-tree  -m -u HEAD
```

This should make the `invisible.js` file disappear from the working directory (and it won't come back on an update).

See the "Sparse checkout" section of the [`git read-tree` documentation](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-read-tree.html) for more information.